# How to Rearrange Blocks on the Category Sidebar

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, sidebar, page-layouts

How can I rearrange the blocks on the sidebar? Where can I edit it? 
Currently the tag block is on the bottom most part of the sidebar. I want to move it up. How am I suppose to do it?

[image: Current Left Sidebar of my Category Page]

Comment: Currently the tag block is on the bottom most part of the sidebar. I want to move it up. How am I suppose to do it?

Comment: Please add more details about your problem so that others can understand. Otherwise, the question might get closed. More info : http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What Magento version are you using? Are you using a custom theme or a Magento default one? Which theme are you using? Did you make any custom changes, if yes, which changes?

Comment: @7ochem it is ok now. the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to `app/design/fronted/base(or your theme contain file)/default/layout/tag.xml` on line `38`

**change**

```
<block type="tag/popular"  name="tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"/>
```

**to**

```
<block type="tag/popular" before="currency" name="tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"/>
```

Comment: I did change it on the base theme but it is not working

Comment: check in your current theme..

Comment: Doesn't have the tag.xml

Comment: try to refresh the cache from admin panel.

Comment: I did it but nothing is changing nor working.

Comment: update the answer kindly check

Comment: I don't know what happened but it is working now... your first code was working... maybe because of the cache or something. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 2):

Use in this way to your `local.xml`

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="core/template" before="-" name="name_of_the_block" template="template_path"/>
</reference>
```

To display as the First block:

```
before="-"
```

To display as the last block:

```
after="-"
```

To display before any other block:

```
 before="block_name"
```

To display after any other block:

```
after="block_name"
```

Comment: Sorry but I am really new to magento. Where can I find the local.xml?

Comment: you are using custom theme

Comment: yes, I am using a custom theme @Kothari

Comment: Check app/design/frontend/package/customtheme/layout/local.xml

Comment: It doesn't have a local.xml

Comment: ok check your base theme it have local.xml just copy paste your theme and edit

Comment: How about I edit it on the base theme? I did check the app/design/frontend/base/default/layout but no local.xml

Comment: check default theme it not there. you create your local.xml under your theme